# Tribblix: cannot start xfce

Tags: xorg, solaris, xfce, opensolaris, illumos

I installed the illumos (opensolaris) distro Tribblix and can't start Xfce. I tried both with a display manager, `slim` (I know it's old, but it's the only one they offer), and from the console. The default Xorg WM, `twm`, however, works perfectly as long as I don't try to run a Xfce programme (e.g. Thunar or Mousepad). Then the entire X server crashes. I've linked to some logs I thought were relevant. Please help!

Xfce log: https://pastebin.com/wQfFBmaX

Xorg log: https://pastebin.com/fYX8NTmJ